# FIX protocol - Why is it critical that market and application are on a sync server time for connection to be handled

Tags: fix-protocol

We are using FIX protocol to connect to a market for trading. Based on the FIX protocol messages, if both counterparties do not use the exact clock (even if it differs by one second or two), then the session is disconnected. Why is this critical in a FIX protocol and how to guarantee that both parties have sync time?

Comment: The disconnections are surely not because of the FIX protocol or the FIX engine used. Can you edit your question with some example messages (along with the log timestamp). E.g. QuickFIX/J by default has a default maximum latency of 2 minutes (not seconds) after which the session is disconnected. Edit: you can guarantee synced time by syncing against a time server.